# How to send multiple variables to codeigniter's view?

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables

I am trying to the array variable `$popular_data` in Codeigniter’s view, it is installed with Modesty script.

I tried to append this variable to the one already passed to view by array_merge, $data + $variable

in Model:

```
public function get_popular_products(){
    $popular_data = $this->db->query(‘SELECT... ’)->result_array();
    return $popular_data;
}
```

in Controller:

```
$this->load->model("Popularproduct_model");
$popularproducts = $this->Popularproduct_model->get_popular_products();
```

`var_dump($popularproducts)` here(in controller) shows the queried popular products on top of view as

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(34) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["title"]=>
    string(13) "Patchouli Oil"
    ["slug"]=>
    string(15) "patchouli-oil-3"
...
```

other variable passed to view as:

```
$this->load->view('index', $data);
```

So how to send the `$popularproducts` to the view and use the values?

Thanks.

Comment: @Moderator,
I have checked the scripts homepage again. It is the " **Modesy** - Marketplace & Classified Ads Script "
Sorry if I confused anyone.

Answer (score 2):

store it in `$data`

```
$data['popularproducts'] = $this->Popularproduct_model->get_popular_products();
```

then make  **foreach**  inside your view.

```
foreach($popularproducts as $data){
  echo $data['title'].'<br>'.
       $data['slug'];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

at first your can add the data in $data['popularproducts'] and then pass it into the view.

```
$data['popularproducts'] = $popularproducts;

$this->load->view('index', $data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make an array with each of variables:

```
$data['variable1'] =  $variable1;

$data['variable2'] =  $variable2;

$data['variable3'] =  $variable3;

$this->load->view('template_name',$data) // add data array here in 2nd parameter
```

Answer (score 0):

> To Pass multiple values from `controller` to `view` you should use an array as below given example
>
> Each variable are as examples, you can convert it as per your requirement

Controller:

```
$data['variable'] =  $variable;//from db or hardcoded

$data['arrayofObject'] =  $arrayofObject;//from db or hardcoded

$data['arrayofArray'] =  $arrayofArray;//from db or hardcoded

$this->load->view('index',$data) // add data array here in 2nd parameter
```

View:

```
i.e:
<div>
     <span><?php echo $variable; ?></span>
</div>
<div>
     <ul>
     <?php if(!empty($arrayofObject)) { ?>
          <?php for($arrayofObject as $obj) { ?>
              <li><?php echo $obj->key; ?></li>
          <?php } ?>
     <?php } ?>
     </ul>
</div>
<div>
     <ul>
     <?php if(!empty($arrayofArray)) { ?>
          <?php for($arrayofArray as $ary) { ?>
              <li><?php echo $ary['key']; ?></li>
          <?php } ?>
     <?php } ?>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining in detail :)

Answer (score 0):

In CodeIgniter, we can send data from Controller to view as an associative array.

The function call `$this->load->view()` has two parameters:

1) View (template) file (path if its not in the default `/application/views` folder.

2) The associative data array to be passed.

```
$data['popularproducts'] = $popularproducts;
$this->load->view('index', $data);
```

If you pass `$data` in above scenario, your template `index.php` has a variable `$popularproducts`.

`$popularproducts` in the template/view is same as you passed from Controller.